# Power supply issue? Or something else (PC turns off)

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-supply

I build a PC about a year ago and I recently put a new graphics card in it (but I don't think that matters). It runs Windows 10.

The symptoms are the following:

1. If I leave the computer on for a while, occasionally it'll go from sleep to some sort of "half on" mode where the power light is flashing and it does nothing (no screen, no response from inputs, etc). It must then be rebooted and it can sometimes be hard to reboot.
2. Sometimes it is hard to turn on (won't respond to power button, etc)
3. I was just using the PC and it flat out turned off on me.

I am starting to think it is issue with the power supply, which is corsair ax 850. I am happy to provide any additional specs.

Comment: Don't know yet from your provided info.  I do know there are possibilties to see things going badly when you have much monitoring things.  Some way to monitor temperatures, and some way to monitor voltages.  Monitoring MIGHT provide clues to your suspect or other suspects. Problem with monitoring late (trying to do it now) you cannot be sure all the sencors and monitor softwares will report correctly.  First & best is any BIOS/UEFI monitoring capability for the board (prior to boot), any software for the board itself for monitoring, & 3rd party monitoring software you can be least sure of.

Comment: When you reboot, does the event log show anything? Does this issue occur is you boot up into safe mode, then open no applications, just leave it to see if the same issue persists